# Python threading lock is condition.acquire similar to lock.acquire

Tags: python, multithreading

Is condition.acquire(threading.Condition()) similar to lock.acquire(threading.Lock). Does both of get access to the lock. Can i use condition.wait,notify with lock.acquire or i have to use condition.wait, notify with condition.acquire.

```
cond.acquire()  // can i replace with lock.acquire

   while count[ipID]> 1:
      cond.wait()
   if ipID == 0:
      time.sleep(10)


   count[ipID] = count[ipID] + 1


   cond.release() // can i replace with lock.release
```

Comment: Why do you _want_ to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If your condition was created like this:

```
lock = Lock()
cond = Condition(lock)
```

… then yes, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition) explain, `cond.acquire()` is just calling `lock.acquire()`, so you could do that instead and get the same effect. And likewise for `release`. However, it's likely to be misleading to human readers (and maybe to static analysis tools), so unless you have a really good reason, you *shouldn't* do it.

---

On the other hand, if they're unrelated objects, created like this:

```
lock = Lock()
cond = Condition()
```

… then no. It is illegal to call `cond.wait()` if you haven't acquired the lock used by the condition. It's guaranteed to raise a `RuntimeError`. It doesn't matter if some other `Lock` object happens to be ensuring that nobody else will access `cond`; the whole point of `cond.wait` is that it atomically releases its lock and blocks on `notify`, so if it's not holding its lock, it's useless as a condition.

---

As a side note, it's almost always better to acquire both `Lock`s and `Condition`s [in a `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement):

```
with cond:
    with count[ipID] > 1:
        cond.wait()
    if ipID == 0:
        time.sleep(10)
    count[ipID] = count[ipID] + 1
```

The way you've written things, if anything after that `acquire` raises an exception, you will never release the condition, so no other thread waiting on it can wake up.

While we're at it, using `sleep` is almost always a sign of a problem with your threading design. Why can't you just `wait(timeout=10)` instead? If you have too many spurious `notify` calls, you should fix that. If `count[ipID]` is not getting reset properly so the `while` loop may exit early, that's even more important to fix. Whatever problem you think you're solving with `sleep`, you're probably just disguising it.

Answer (score 2):

The notify part of code is as below.

```
print "count is %d %s" % (count[ipID],name)

   cond.acquire()

   count[ipID] = count[ipID] - 1
   cond.notifyAll()
   cond.release()
```